# PDA to recognize a language

Tags: automata, pushdown-automata

The PDA has to recognize the language $L = \{w\in \{a,b,c\}^* \mid |w|_a = |w|_b$ or $ |w|_a=|w|_b\}$. 
Currently I have an automaton which recognises that language if $|w_a|=|w|_b$ xor $|w_a|=|w|_c$. It looks like this:[image: PDA]

It is xor because it is going to empty the stack before it could check next letter's  occurence. 
My question is how can I divide this into two PDAs (one recognises $|w|_a=|w|_b$ and the other one recognises $|w|_a=|w|_c$) and take the union of those PDAs? 
 Or is there any better solution?

Comment: Do you actually need to produce a PDA? If not, producing a PDA for $\#a=\#b$ is enough, since $\#a=\#c$ is essentially identical and context-free languages are closed under taking unions. Alternatively, nondeterminism is your friend.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

actually you also had a mistake in the definition of the problem and I've considered its |Wa|=|Wb| or |Wa|=|Wc|.
Any way using non-deterministic I've tried to separate two conditions:
[image: NPDA - the upper way specify equality a's & b's and so on]